# "Sorry, only tenant administrators can add or give access to this app."

Tags: third-party-software, sharepoint-store

I'm trying to install a third party app from the SharePoint store and I'm getting the following error:

> "Sorry, only tenant administrators can add or give access to this
>   app."

My account is part of the Farm Administrator's group and is also a site collection administrator and local admin on the server. I'm working with their support to try and get to the bottom of it but as per usual, I have to do my due diligence to prove that the problem isn't on my end before they'll provide any further support.

Is there some site configuration that I need to set up to get this to work? I can install pretty much any other app from the store.

Comment: after adding yourself in Local admin did you logoff and log back? also IISreset?

Comment: I have to manage the server so I've been local admin since I started working here almost 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If talking about on-premise installation of SharePoint, i will suggest the following trick (which helped me): 
1. Go to 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\CONFIG
2. Grab the required XML file (for example, AppPermissionProvider.Search.xml  for addin with search requirements and so on)
3. Change

```
<Alias Name="Search" Value="http://sharepoint/search" RequiredRight="TenantAdmin" />
```

to

```
<Alias Name="Search" Value="http://sharepoint/search" RequiredRight="SiteCollectionAdmin" />
```

4. Save the XML file, try to add the addin again.

Also as a second workaround try to add yourself to local administrators directly, not by group and also do the same for farm administrators (not via group).
Don't forget to do iisreset after it.

Comment: I did all steps you mentioned. But didn't work. Also as per question Dan S asked to "add an App". Please specify which specific file to be edited. Please don't give example.

Comment: It depends on the app type you're trying to add. For simplicity, if this is an app which is using Search capabilities then AppPermissionProvider.Search.xml file should be modified. In fact, files by mask `AppPermissionProvider.*.xml` should be modified where `*` is a required (used in your app) provider.